# CURL for WAMP

Tags: curl, wamp, libcurl

I’m new to PHP and I’m trying to learn how to parse information, I’m trying to use CURL but I’m not able to install it on my desktop WAMP on Windows Vista. How do I install CURL?

Comment: Which CURL? if you mean cURL - http://curl.haxx.se/ - then it's not a parser, but a comms library.

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a bug somewhere. If you are experiencing this on Windows 7 64 bit then try installing Apache addon version 2.2.9 and PHP addon version 5.3.1 and switching to those in WAMP and then activating the CURL extension. That worked for me.

You can download it from http://www.wampserver.com/en/.

Answer (score 3):

Check out *[cURL with PHP and Apache on Windows](http://www.tonyspencer.com/2003/10/22/curl-with-php-and-apache-on-windows/)* for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Add a similar issue.
Fixed once I upgraded to the latest version of Wampserver 64x here http://www.wampserver.com/