# How to solve Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Gigya.Socialize needs the CURL PHP extension.' sdk\GSSDK.php on line 12

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have installed https://wordpress.org/plugins/gigya-socialize-for-wordpress/installation/ plugin. But after installation its showing :

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Gigya.Socialize needs the CURL PHP extension.' in C:\wamp\www\sports\wp-content\plugins\gigya-socialize-for-wordpress\sdk\GSSDK.php on line 12

Can anyone tell me how I can solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to check the status of the PHP cURL module by creating the following php page:

```
<? phpinfo(); ?>
```

Load this page in your browser and it will tell you whether cURL is installed/enabled.

More information regarding installing cURL on WAMP can be found here:
[How to enable curl in Wamp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021536/how-to-enable-curl-in-wamp-server)
and here:
[WAMP Curl installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486592/wamp-curl-installation)