# PHP cURL not working - WAMP on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: php, curl, wamp

I got my [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) installed on my windows 7 64bit. cURL is not working, but still I got it enabled from the WAMP tray.

I have also uncommented `extension=php_curl.dll` in `php.ini` for both the PHP and Apache folder.

Windows give me an error message,

> PHP Startup: unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext/php_curl.dll' - the application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-lin sxstrace.exe tool for more detail."

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I use XAMPP personally, I find WAMP to be too buggy in many areas.  You may want to give that a shot if nothing else is working.

Comment: I love wamp, i never have an issue with it

Comment: I'd say your best bet is to revert to Apache v2.2.9 and PHP v5.3.1.

Comment: This seems to still be an issue in WAMP running PHP 5.4.13 and apache 2.4.4. Curl was working fine and then stopped and my script dies. Now just a simple curl init causes issue (the only thing in the file). Any updated patch sources?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107356/apache-2-4-23-php7-x-windows-10-x64-php-curl-not-working

Answer (score 310, accepted):

Go to http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/ and download the cURL version that corresponds to your [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) version **under "Fixed curl extensions:"**.

So if you have PHP 5.3.13, download "php_curl-5.3.13-VC9-x64.zip". Try the "VC" version first. Then replace the php_curl.dll in ext folder. This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I was going nuts over it. The deal is, it works, but not for curl_multi !!! Anyway, it pointed my in the right direction. I just went to wamp's website and downloaded the Apache add-on ver. 2.2.9 and PHP add-on ver. 5.3.1. With those in use, it works. Morale: not all that's latest version is best.

Comment: Make sure to kill the httpd, wampmanager and all processes - and then start the wamp application again. Otherwise it sometimes doesn't really reload..

Comment: Make sure you download the VC version of curl that corresponds to your PHP version, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Don't work for me either, i tried everthing, can someone can connect to my PC and check it out? or advice me how to solve it, i did everything

Comment: for newbies like me: replacing the file is not enough, you also need to re-enable curl extension: click wamp tray icon / php /  php extensions / php_curl

Comment: I'm using Windows8 x64 and re-starting WAMP wasn't enough, I had to restart my computer to make changes work for me.

Comment: The file that worked for me was `php_curl-5.3.13-VC9-x64.zip`.

Comment: anything for 32 bit version ?

Comment: What about PHP 5.5 and VC11? Does anyone have a working php_curl.dll for that setup?

Comment: This solution is not a fix for PHP 7 because there are no "fixed curl extensions".  In this situation I copied the libssh2.dll, ssleay32.dll, and  libeay32.dll files into the apache24/bin/ directory (It already had one of these and I didn't overwrite it).  I tried everything else and this was the only thing that worked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107356/apache-2-4-23-php7-x-windows-10-x64-php-curl-not-working

Answer (score 25):

I had the same exact issue. After trying almost everything and digging on Stack Overflow, I finally found the reason. Try downloading "fixed curl extension" separately from *[PHP 5.4.3 and PHP 5.3.13 x64 (64 bit) for Windows](http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/)*.

I've downloaded "php_curl-5.4.3-VC9-x64", and it worked for me. I hope it helps.

Comment: this is a good solution, replace a dll file and no need to downgrade.

Comment: In addition to doing this I also found that I needed to upgrade to the latest version of WAMP and add the php bin folder to my %PATH% variable.

Answer (score 13):

Works for me:

- Go to [this link](http://www.anindya.com)
- Download *php_curl-5.4.3-VC9-x64.zip* under "Fixed curl extensions:"
- Replace the `php_curl.dll` file in the `ext` folder.

This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I downloaded php_curl-5.3.13-VC9-x64.zip from that link for PHP 5.3.13 and it works fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107356/apache-2-4-23-php7-x-windows-10-x64-php-curl-not-working

Answer (score 5):

I have struggled a lot with this myself.. In the end, PHP version 5.3.1 with Apache 2.2.9 worked...

I was getting the consistent error of missing php5.dll. For this, I renamed all the old `php.ini` files which are not required (outside of the WAMP folder) to `old_ohp.ini`.

Comment: I tried everything, from the answer above to re-installing WAMP.  Finally I gave this a shot, and it's running nicely now with PHP 5.3.1 and Apach 2.2.9.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The error is unrelated to PHP. It means you are somehow relying on Apache's mod_deflate, but that Apache module is not loaded. Try enabling mod_deflate in httpd.conf or commenting out the offending line (search for DEFLATE in httpd.conf).

As for the PHP curl extension, you must make sure it's activated in php.ini. Make sure extension_diris set to the directory php_curl.dll is in:

extension_dir = "C:/whatever"
and then add

extension=php_curl.dll

Comment: This worked for me PHP7 Win 10 64 bit. Added the following to php.ini:
extension_dir = "C:\php\ext"
extension=php_curl.dll
>>Also add C:\php to PATH in User and System variables

Answer (score 2):

The steps are as follows:

1. Close WAMP (if running)
2. Navigate to `WAMP\bin\php\<your version of PHP>`
3. Edit file `php.ini`
4. Search for curl, uncomment `extension=php_curl.dll`
5. Navigate to `WAMP\bin\Apache\<your version of Apache>\bin\`
6. Edit file php.ini
7. Search for curl, uncomment `extension=php_curl.dll`
8. Save both
9. Restart WAMP

Comment: This worked for me on a 64bit installation of WAMP ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think cURL doesn't work with WAMP 2.2e. I tried all your solutions, but it still did not work. I got the previous version, (2.2d) and it works.

So just download the previous version :D

Answer (score 0):

Well, just uninstall WAMP 64-bit and go with the 32-bit version. It worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've managed to load CURL correctly. In my case php was installed from zip package, so I had to add php directory to PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your system PATH environment variable contains the directory in which PHP is installed.
Stop the Apache server and restart it once more. With luck CURL will start working.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:  http://www.mediafire.com/?3ay381k3cq59cm2
download a paste the file in ext folder
PHP 5.4.3

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem with not working curl on win8 wamp3 php5.6. Reinstalling wamp (x64 version as I had x64 in system info) made it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

uncomment `"curl=cainfo"` in the `php.ini` document
This helped me when installing Prestashop when all other methods still did not work.

Answer (score -2):

This is what worked for me

Answered by Soren from another SO thread - [CURL for WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693385/curl-for-wamp?rq=1)

"There seems to be a bug somewhere. If you are experiencing this on Win 7 64 bit then try installing apache addon version 2.2.9 and php addon version 5.3.1 and switching to those in WAMP and then activating the CURL extension. That worked for me."