# curl is activated but is not showing in phpinfo

Tags: php, curl, wamp

I have a problem that `curl` is not showing in phpinfo  as i am using `wampserver(64 bit)` but when i open php and then php extensions a tick is placed in front of `php_curl` in my wamp server but still curl is not displayed in phpinfo.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try restarting the server. Hit control + f5 to refresh the browser.

Comment: I have done this several a times...still same results... i have done both the processes.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue myself a couple of days ago, the only way I could fix it is by installing apache addon version 2.2.9 and php addon version 5.3.1

Both are available in the addons section of the download page at http://www.wampserver.com/en

EDIT::
This only happened to me on my 64bit laptop, my 32bit desktop runs the latest versions just fine with no issues

Also... if you look in (C):\wamp\logs\apache_error (or whatever path you've installed to) I suspect you will see an error similar to this..

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext/php_curl.dll' - The application has
>   failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect.
>   Please see the application event log or use the command-line
>   sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

Since this question is fairly old now and since I've experienced this issue again on my new laptop, and other users have visited the answer I've given here.. It appears if you use the 32bit installation of wampserver, even on a 64bit platform, this issue doesn't occur and it's the easiest way to avoid it.

Comment: I have the same issue. Will try downloading those versions

Comment: I had the same issue on Windowns 7 64 bit. And I can confirm that installing those specific versions of Apache and PHP worked!

Comment: Sure enough... I always like to keep up-to-date on software, but - changing back to these 2 exact versions, then going back through and enabling curl...etc got it to work. Thanks!

Comment: So keep in mind that you have to get both the newer apache and php and they have to go together.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with curl library on Windows 7 x64 but i just downloaded fixed version of php_curl.dll library from here: http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/ and it was well.

Comment: Yes, i have downloaded [fixed php_curl-5.4.3 for x64](http://www.mediafire.com/file/3ay381k3cq59cm2/php_curl-5.4.3-VC9-x64.zip) and it works!

Comment: It's best to use 32 bit versions of Apache and PHP as they are a lot less problematic.

Answer (score 2):

This is where I finally found my answer:
[PHP cURL not working - WAMP on Windows 7 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939248/php-curl-not-working-wamp-on-windows-7-64-bit)

There, Matthieu Napoli says:

> Go to
>   http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/
>   and download the curl version that corresponds to your php version
>   under "Fixed curl extensions:".
>
> So if you have php 5.3.13, download "php_curl-5.3.13-VC9-x64.zip". Try
>   the "VC" version first. Then replace the php_curl.dll in ext folder.
>   This worked for me.