# Call to undefined function curl_init(), but it's enabled

Tags: php, curl, wamp

I have WAMP and I am running PHP 5.3.13 with Apache 2.2.22.

I have enabled the extension by ticking php_curl. I have restarted my computer.

My code is saying:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()
```

Anyone think what might be going wrong?

My phpinfo does not say anything about curl but in the phpini it says:

;extension=php_bz2.dll

extension=php_curl.dll
.

Code calling it is here:

```
class ***** {
  public static $oauth, $debug, $logger, $session_manager, $last_response;
  protected static $url, $client_id, $client_secret, $secret, $ch, $headers;

  const GET = 'GET';
  const POST = 'POST';
  const PUT = 'PUT';
  const DELETE = 'DELETE';

  public static function setup($client_id, $client_secret, $options = array('session_manager' => '*****Session')) {
  // Setup client info
  self::$client_id = $client_id;
  self::$client_secret = $client_secret;

  // Setup curl
  self::$url = empty($options['api_url']) ? 'https://api.*****.com:443' : $options['api_url'];
  self::$debug = false;
  self::$ch = curl_init();
```

This code comes from a trustworthy API. I have starred words that need not be shared.

Comment: Then you don't actually have it enabled. Refer to the documentation on how to enable it.

Comment: this doesn't help. I have come here because I have referred to the documentation

Comment: What have you did so far, Put up the code.

Comment: added to Q - its an api that has worked on old wamp installation but not this one. I'm on windows 8 if that's any help

Comment: `;extension=php_bz2.dll extension=php_curl.dll` in the same line? Try putting `extension=php_curl.dll` in its own line

Comment: nah, that's just the RTE here. it wont separate the line without a big gap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the dll file found in ext folder with the correct version here:

http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/

I am using win 8 64bit so the version for me was:

http://www.mediafire.com/?0hm40owj08y68p7

Comment: i have same situation, same 64bit Win8, but replacing the dll didn't work for me. Did you do anything else to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Look in your php.ini file for this line:

`;extension=php_curl.dll`

If its there, delete the **;** from the beginning then restart the server and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by chance using the 64bit edition of wampserver?

There's an issue (it seems) with either the 64bit edition, or certain combinations of Apache versions / PHP versions

If you go to the download section of the [wampserver homepage](http://www.wampserver.com/en) you can download different Apache / PHP version to test until you find one that works.

[I have answered this kind of question before here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11733864/1207346). Hope it can shed some light on the situation.

From my other answer:

> I ran into this issue myself a couple of days ago, the only way I could fix it is by installing apache addon version 2.2.9 and php addon version 5.3.1

Comment: Ah.. ill give other V's a try.

Comment: I should add that even on my 64bit laptop I can use the latest versions of the 32bit and everything is fine

Comment: Hm. doesn't start up services. port 80 is fine if you were wondering. There was an error in the install it says missing dll. I'll give a few of the other 32bit setups a try then fallback on XAMP

Comment: None of the setups are working and now my services wont start up properly!

Comment: @JamesT Uninstall, do a clean install, make sure you stop all wamp services before doing the uninstall

Comment: Right. done a clean install.. services are running. curl still not working. I'm gnna redownload a version of the curl dll and see if theres a problem with the original set up one.

Comment: @JamesT Good luck fella, sorry I can't be of more help.