# Call to undefined function curl_init in php 5.2.6 XAMPP 1.6.8 Windows Server

Tags: php, apache, curl, xampp

I get an error on my php application :
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()

I have searched everywhere for the answer and trust me I've done every solution given but still failed to overcome this problem.
By far I've tried several solutions such as :

1. Removing the comment ";" in php.ini before the extension=php_curl.dll and then restart the  server
2. Go to http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/ and download the fixed curl extensions there and replace the php_curl.dll in xampp/php/ext with the downloaded dlls (each one of them one by one) and then restart the server
3. Change the extension=php_curl.dll to extension="C:\Xampp\php\ext\php_curl.dll" and then restart the server

All the solutions just didn't work for my case. I think the server runs the older version of XAMPP and PHP (XaMPP 1.6.8 with PHP 5.2.6), is it the source of my problem?

I definitely desperate for some help, for I already tried all the solutions provided in the similar questions in stackoverflow (trust me, there's a lot of em) and still I couldn't get the answer to my problem. So please dont rush yourself from labeling this post as a duplicate, cause I tried just almost all of em.

Your help will be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that you change the correct php.ini file? You need to find which php configuration file apache is loading. Also try the `phpinfo();` function to see if the `curl` extension is loaded.

Comment: yes i've tried the phpinfo() and I changed the corresponding php.ini file which was shown on the "Loaded configuration file" section which is in my case located in C:\XAMPP\apache\bin\php.ini

Comment: Are you sure that you have downloaded the correct version of curl - 32bit  / 64bit ?

Comment: @caesardo can you add to your questions the sections from `phpinfo()` results that are about `curl` ?

Comment: @SamuilBanti the xampp came with the built in php_curl.dll in the ext directory, so i just uncomment the extension=php_curl.dll . As for the fixed curl in http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/ , I'm really not sure because the php version of the fixed curl extension didn't match the php version on my Apache module. The link provide the fixed curl for php 5.3.13 and 5.4 while my php version is 5.2.6

Comment: @Athafoud there is no curl section in my phpinfo() , I think it was because the curl extension isn't properly loaded (or not loaded at all)

Comment: @caesardo I guess an update of php will help. Check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733765/curl-is-activated-but-is-not-showing-in-phpinfo

Comment: @SamuilBanti for sure uninstalling the current configuration and installing an updated one (xampp 1.8.3) or a similar one (wamp) will help. Also my opinion is if you have the expertise to go with a pure apache, php, mysql configuration. It will make your life easier!