# window 8 64bit RTM & PhP Curl enabling

Tags: php, windows, curl, 64-bit, wamp

i have a Windows 8 RTM 64 bit installed on a machine.
Also i installed wampserver2.2e-php5.3.13-httpd2.2.22-mysql5.5.24-x64 on it.
But the php CURL extention just wont work on it...

I tried enabling in both php.ini files the extention, tried varios dlls from the net but still no luck with it... Q_Q

Did somone make it work? and if so which dll are you using?

Comment: it could be a problem with the distribution. Can you download another distribution and try again. I am saying this because it has happened to me, and downloading another distribution from wamp site fixed it.

Comment: I tried several distros.... like from 5.2 to 5.4 and all ahve the curl broken... Q_Q

Comment: can you paste the errors from error log here please!

Comment: furthermore, is there a possibility of running wamp under windows 7 compatibility mode?  have you tried something like that?

Comment: Done it tried... none works still!!! No distro for 8th yet Q_Q

Comment: try installing curl extension from here.   http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/. Under fixed CURL extension at the bottom of the page.

Comment: have a look at this too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939248/php-curl-not-working-wamp-on-windows-7-64-bit

Comment: *Disclaimer: shameless self-promotion follows*. PHP's curl extension is a pretty terrible API. I would suggest avoiding it altogether in favor of [Artax for PHP5.4+](https://github.com/rdlowrey/Artax).

Comment: Idiotic, needless remark follows: from the pertormanse it is better, i am stuck with it... and... failed self promotion :)