# PHP extension "curl" must be loaded

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to install a Magento on my server, and when I get to "Configuration", the installation launches:
    PHP extension "curl" must be loaded.

I've checked my php.ini, and **extension=php_curl.dll** is not commented. For both Apache and PHP folders. I also checked my Wamp manager, and it looks like this:

[image: My PHP info].

So I guess that my php_curl is working fine... But I still get the same message when I install Magento:

[image: My Magento installation].

Any idea on what's wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem. The **mod_curl** extension in wamp has a bug.

You can replace it with a newer version. I don't know which PHP-Version you use but here you can download a newer version. Download a TS (TheadSafe) version of the module and replace it with your existing curl module.

http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/

And a helpfull post:

http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,85716

Comment: I'm using PHP: 5.4.3
          Apache: 2.4.2
          MySQL: 5.5.24
And I'm gonna check what you linked... :)

Comment: ok this is a problem. There is no module for 5.4 which is really working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939248/wamp-php-on-windows-7

Comment: Look here. http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/ here you can download a new module. I had the same problem and switched to 5.3 and Apache 2.2 there are the most module and its working well.

Answer (score 0):

Replaced the old `php_curl.dll` with the new one in `\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext\` by downloading from  http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/  .
Now its working. It is the error with recent wamp installation package.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the php.ini files in your xampp folder. Three files in three different places need to be changed.

Follow the following steps to enable curl library with XAMPP in Windows:

**Step 1:**

Browse and open the following 3 files

```
C:\Program Files\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini
C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini
C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php4\php.ini
```

**Step 2:**

Uncomment the following line in your php.ini file by removing the semicolon (;).

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

After that it will look something like something below-

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

**Step 3:**

Restart your Apache server.

**Step 4:**

Check your phpinfo() to see whether curl has properly enabled or not.

Enjoy using curl() library.