# curl on WAMP server

Tags: php, curl, wamp

I am new to webbscrapping and php .How ever i was trying this simple php curl code but output comes out blank. i.e i get a blank webpage when i run the following code

```
    <?
    $url = "oooff.com";
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $curl_scraped_page;
    ?>
```

I am using Wamp server 2 on a windows 7 64 bit pc. i have uncommented php_curl.dll the php.ini files in both apache/bin and php/bin in the wamp . I have checked the php_curl extention on the wamp server. still i get a blank webpage. What can be the problem?
Any suggestions will be helpful

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please check in phpinfo() curl is enabled or not ?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your log? Try to use `var_dump` on `$curl_scraped_page` instead of `echo`.

Comment: Have you restarted your apache/wamp?

Comment: check your curl_info()

Comment: @Praveenkalal I ve chked in phpinfo().curl is enabled there

Comment: @h2ooooooo tried both still blank

Comment: @KeesSonnema restarted the wamp about 3 times already.. still no change

Comment: @ianace Where do i check curl_info ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things you can check:
See this link for enabling curl in wamp on windows.

http://www.phpmind.com/blog/2011/02/how-to-enable-curl-in-wamp/

**Most likely solution:**

You have to replace the php_curl.dll with the following:
This version for windows is compatible with wamp.
You have to replace it in the PHP extensions tab in wamp server.

Look for Fixed curl extensions and choose your php version.
http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/

I've got this from another SO Post and this worked for a lot of people.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13677593/1379394

Comment: i did this and i got fatal error:Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\wamp\www\scrappingphpcurl.php on line 3

Comment: Finally!! i just used addon apache version 2.2.9 and php 5.3.1 and voila it worked!!!!

Comment: Actually Kees, if he installed the new addons to get it working your answer did not solve his question!

Comment: I know. But he asked for a solution, and the problem is solved. When he occures a new problem. He can ask a new question any time :)