# Strange error trying to execute "php codecept.phar run > result.txt"

Tags: php, wamp

I have installed Codeception following the guide on their website. Everything went okay, so I created my first basic test.

```
<?php
$I = new WebGuy($scenario);
$I->wantTo('ensure that frontpage works');
$I->amOnPage('/'); 
$I->see('Homepage');
```

Trying to execute this and it gave Stack trace errors so I dumped them in `result.txt` page.

```
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v1.6.2
Powered by PHPUnit 3.7.19 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER - assumed 'CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER' in phar://C:/wamp/www/dugun/codecept.phar/src/Codeception/Configuration.php on line 175

Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_CERTINFO - assumed 'CURLOPT_CERTINFO' in phar://C:/wamp/www/dugun/codecept.phar/src/Codeception/Configuration.php on line 175

Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER - assumed 'CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER' in phar://C:/wamp/www/dugun/codecept.phar/src/Codeception/Module/PhpBrowser.php on line 78

Fatal error: Call to undefined function Guzzle\Http\Curl\curl_version() in phar://C:/wamp/www/dugun/codecept.phar/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlVersion.php on line 47
```

Using WAMP on Windows 7. PHP ver 5.4.3. Apache ver 2.4.2. CURL is enabled in settings. Tried restarting several times, no luck.

Anyone knows how to solve this issue, what may be wrong?

**Update**
The problem was related to curl.dll. Downloading a fresh one from this topic ([PHP cURL not working - WAMP on Windows 7 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939248/php-curl-not-working-wamp-on-windows-7-64-bit)) solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the errors I'd guess that CURL is missing even though it's enabled, try running a phpinfo() to see if the extension is running.

From the PHP site:

"Note: Note to Win32 Users
 In order to enable this module on a Windows environment, libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll must be present in your PATH.  You don't need libcurl.dll from the cURL site."

http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php

Comment: Nothing is written about CURL in PhpInfo. Also "curl --help" works in commandline. Ssleay and libeay dll's are correctly placed.

Comment: This is not exactly the answer but I'll accept it since the problem was related to CURL not loading. Refer to my question's bottom part to see answer in a different question.