# curl is not working on php 5.4.3 of wamp server

Tags: php, curl, web, wamp, composer-php

I am using wamp server that installs php version 5.4.3 and I enabled curl extension, edited php.ini files to uncomment curl extensions lines but the problem is that when I try installing composer using console, it gives me a message that says "PHP Startup: unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext/php_curl.dll", here is a screenshot of it

[image]

I followed instruction from different posts, downloaded curl versions from [anindya](http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/) but with no hope..

Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your dll is compiled for the version of PHP you're using. So one compiled for 5.5 won't work on 5.4, etc. There's a link in this question that's relevant

[PHP cURL not working - WAMP on Windows 7 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939248/php-curl-not-working-wamp-on-windows-7-64-bit)

Comment: This question is where I got that link I posted from, I made sure of everything and nothing solved

Comment: Hmm... could I recommend Easy PHP then? Mine came with the right libcurl installed http://www.easyphp.org/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are running a 32bit PHP and have downloaded a 64bit version of PHP_CURL. **That wont work**

This dll should come as standard with WAMP's PHP's.

Are you sure your problem was not that you forgot that when running PHP in CLI mode you have to configure it using the 'php.ini' file that lives in the c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.ini

So if you uncomment the php_curl extension line in that file it should have worked, until you downloaded the wrong curl dll.

So get a 32bit curl dll for the correct version of php and try again.