# PHP CURL not loading in WAMP after upgrading PHP from 5.3.4 to 5.3.22

Tags: php, apache, curl, installation, wamp

I have the exact same issue as [PHP cURL not working - WAMP on Windows 7 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939248/php-curl-not-working-wamp-on-windows-7-64-bit)

> CURL doesn't load at Apache restart, with message: "PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.22/ext/php_curl.dll' - The operating system cannot run %1.\r\n in Unknown on line 0"

Except that I am not installing 5.3.13 as in the other thread but I am attempting to upgrade PHP in an existing WAMP installation from 5.3.4 to 5.3.22, both x64 VC9 TS on a Win 2008R2 64 bits, running Apache 2.2.4 x64.

I did the following steps:

- stopped Apache
- unzip php5.3.22 in /wamp/bin/php5.3.22;
- updated php.ini, httpd.conf and the 2 Wamp config files to point to the new PHP version;
- updated php5ts.dll and php5isapi.dll in Apache\bin with the new ones
- updated Windows PATH to point to php5.3.22 folder instead of php5.3.4
- restarted Apache -> CURL load error message

I could try most of the answers provided in other threads except the one from Matthieu:

> Go to http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/ and download the curl version that corresponds to your php version under "Fixed curl extensions:".

...as there is no "Fixed curl extension" for 5.3.22 in Anindya's site.

Does anyone know if there is need or not for a "fixed curl lib" after 5.3.13? and where I can find it?

Comment: Sorry, this site is for implementation issues only (read: programming questions). Have a try over at the superuser.com site.

Comment: @arkascha: wouldn't this be better on _Server Fault_?

Comment: @arkascha: WAMP setups are generally used as a development tool; such questions would be better off here than on Super User. FYI: [this question is being discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208042/inappropriate-welcome-to-new-users).

Comment: @halfer: WAMP is generally used as a development tool rather than in production systems - while [the latter is nominally on-topic for Server Fault](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1968/what-to-do-with-xampp-mamp-wamp-questions), unless you know the asker *isn't* using it for development recommending they go there is a bad idea.

Comment: Ouch! but message received, @Shog.

Answer (score 3):

Either there are some typos in your question or you have done a few things wrong.

The new PHP should have gone into \wamp\bin\php\php5.3.22
*updated php5ts.dll and php5isapi.dll in Apache\bin with the new ones* This is done by Switching versions in WAMP, you dont do it manually

*updated Windows PATH to point to php5.3.22 folder instead of php5.3.4* There is no need to put PHP on the PATH, in fact it reduces the ability of WAMPServer to switch between various versions of PHP.

Have a look at this it may help [How to install a version of PHP into an existing WAMP install](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,119182,119190#msg-119190)

Comment: Hello and thanks for the hints.

Yes I did a few things manually instead of using WAMP version management, fixed that. And I could finally fix the CURL issue.

However I realize, only now, that Curl multi_exec crashes Apache.
I'm using PHP 5.3.22 - TS - VC9/x64 on Win Server 2008 R2
With CUrl 7.29 / Host: x86_64-pc-win32.

So I'm looking for a solution to upgrade php_curl to a new release / different build that someone would have validated for multi_exec ?

rgds, pierre