# Calling curl_multi_init() causes script to terminate

Tags: php, curl, wampserver

I'm trying to use curl_multi for the first time and am doing testing on my local development machine using WampServer. I can call `curl_init()` without any problem, but when I try doing this:

```
$mh = curl_multi_init();
```

Chrome shows a page saying "No data received." So it's like the script just stops running and no output is returned.

What might be causing this problem?

EDIT:

Example 1:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(100);

echo 'test1';
$mh = curl_init();
echo 'test2';

die();
```

Output 1:

```
test1test2
```

Example 2:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(100);

echo 'test1';
$mh = curl_multi_init();
echo 'test2';

die();
```

Output 2:

```
No data received

Reload
```

Comment: Are you on shared hosting?

Comment: @BenjaminDeBos This is happening on my Windows computer. I'm running WampServer.

Comment: Maybe related to that same problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939248/php-curl-not-working-wamp-on-windows-7-64-bit
Have you tried running a code that is known to work? Anything in the log relevant to the problem?

Comment: @Maxime I tried replacing the DLL like that answer said, but that results in the following error showing: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_multi_init() `, so no joy.

Comment: @Maxime I tried all of the other DLL's on the page linked to in that answser, and one of them worked! Make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be related to [that same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939248/php-curl-not-working-wamp-on-windows-7-64-bit).
The cURL DLL in WampServer is known to be buggy. Yet, so far, it wouldn't activate itself within the PHP extensions menu rather than causing that issue. Interesting to know!