# PHP 5.5 cURL not working on Windows 7 64 bit PHP 5.5 VC11

Tags: php, curl, wamp

I'm having trouble getting the CURL extension to work on PHP 5.5 ts-VC11 on Win7 64 bit. The supplied `php_curl.dll` loads but does nothing (doesn't register itself as a curl extension) without throwing any error.

I know there is a **[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939248/php-curl-not-working-wamp-on-windows-7-64-bit)** for running a patched `php_curl.dll` on PHP 5.3 and 5.4 on Windows 64 bit, but I have to use PHP **5.5 64 bit**, and I can't find a working CURL extension for that.

Is there a solution?

Comment: One solution would be to use the 32bit version of WAMP. Afterall 64bit PHP on a windows environment is still flagged as Experimental on the PHP website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WAMPServer version prior to 2.5:

All you need to do is copy libeay32.dll and libssl32.dll from the PHP `\wamp\bin\php\{phpversion}`folder to the `\wamp\bin\apache\{apacheversion}\bin` folder.

If you are using WAMPServer 2.5 you dont even need to do that as SYMLINKS should  automatically get created for you. If the symlinks are not there then just do this to create them:-

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Version ( and click on the version number you are using )
```

It is very bad practice when using WAMPServer to put anything in the `\windows\` folder structure as this will cause problems when/if you decide to switch between versions of Apache and/or PHP.

Answer (score 0):

It works now with the original `php_curl.dll`. The issue seems to have been a conflict in ssleay dll's. Just adding PHP to the PATH didn't solve the issue, but copying `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` to `C:\Windows\System32` did (note -- on WAMP its better to copy these to the Apache bin folder).

Comment: You dont actually need to put them in either of these directories. All you need to do is copy libeay32.dll and libssl32.dll from the PHP folder to the Apache\bin folder.

Comment: I did it this way because my `apache\bin` folder already had newer versions of those DLLs, so I didn't want to overwrite those. But certainly it might have worked your way, too (I only needed this for local development on Windows, not for WAMP).

Comment: Ok but the same applies even if you are not using WAMPServer specifically. If your Apache folder already had newer versions, where did they come from. Can I assume you have at least 2 versions of PHP available to you?

Comment: They came with the *[Apache 2.4.10 Win64](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/)* package from apachelounge.

Comment: Yes, but a its PHP that is using these files the ones from the PHP delivery are the ones that should be used

Comment: `mod_ssl` from apache is also using those files.

Comment: Yup, but as the ones that come with Apache dont normally work we copy the ones that come with PHP, which normally do work, over them.

Comment: Adding PHP's path to system Path variable worked for me.