# Call to undefined function curl_init() after updating PHP version in WAMP

Tags: php, curl, wamp, wampserver, php-curl

I've been using WAMP for a long time without any problems with PHP 7.2.4. Today I've updated my PHP to 7.4.19 and it seems the cURL extension is not loading properly, I am getting the `curl_init()` error.

- php.ini is configured correctly in `php7.4.19` folder,
  `extension=curl` is uncommented, so is the php.ini file in apache/bin
  folder, which is basically just a link to the same file from the PHP
  directory
- I've tried unchecking the cURL extension and turning it on
  again from WAMP settings and also directly in php.ini by commenting
  it, followed by restarting the WAMP or even Windows
- in `phpinfo()` I
  can clearly see the cURL is not being loaded, if I switch back to
  7.2.4 however and refresh the page, cURL loads just fine
- I've tried copying the php_curl.dll from 7.2.4 /ext directory, to the current 7.4.19 /ext
  directory and rewriting the file
- I've tried adding
  `extension=php_curl.dll` to php.ini as well

The system PATH is correctly configured. As I mentioned, it works well with older version of PHP, which uses the same system PATH.

**System info:**

- WAMP 3.2.5 x64
- Apache 2.4.33
- PHP 7.4.19
- MySQL and MariaDB probably not relevant at all
- Windows 10 x64 with most recent updates

Basically I've tried everything I found online. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You probably need to update php_curl.dll. This one should be able to help you out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939248/php-curl-not-working-wamp-on-windows-7-64-bit#10977022 Get the correct version of php_curl.dll and replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very dumb of me, but I finally solved it, leaving this answer here in case anyone struggles with the same problem.

**I needed to update Apache from 2.4.33 to 2.4.47**. Seems like the .33 version had problems with loading the cURL extension in PHP 7.4 for some reason.

Comment: next time it happens, make sure to set `display_startup_errors=On` and `display_errors =On` in php.ini as well, they'd probably tell you where the php loading failed