# PHP Curl Not enable

Tags: php, curl

I have compile php and curl on my server.
When i run phpinfo() on browser it does not show that curl is enable.
When i run from the command line it shows curl is enable.

Here is the command:
/opt/php -r "phpinfo();"

I have also created /usr/bin php as symlink

I have also compiled php --with-curl=[curl path] as static not as shared.

What I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you restarted Apache?

Comment: May I know which server you are using ie. WAMP,XAMPP or MAMP??

Comment: this link is for xampp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347146/how-to-enable-curl-in-php-xampp

Comment: for wamp, refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693385/curl-for-wamp?lq=1

Comment: I am not using any of the lamp stack.

Answer (score 0):

Is it enabled through php.ini. Although curl might have been compiled with php but it might have been disabled through php.ini settings file. Confirm once that curl actually has been enabled.

Comment: @PaulSmith Seems like many have the same problem https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59028 Try to follow the list. Even though most of them are related to solr and libcurl issues. But you might find some helpful answer there. Also this piece of advice ```The supported versions of libcurl and libxml have been lowered to 7.15.5 and 2.6.26 respectively so there is no need now to build libcurl and libxml2 from source on older RHEL, Fedora Core and CentOS systems.

This is true as of SVN revision 298824``` seems to be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using XAMPP, uncomment the line

;extension=php_curl.dll
in xampp\apache\bin\php.ini, and then restart the Apache service.

NB: In newer XAMPP versions, PHP has moved to root xampp folder xampp\php\php.ini.

Comment: I am not using XAMPP or any other lamp stack